# pandas: Select rows by diff with previous columns, but only one time per row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like below

```
ID value
1 10
2 15
3 18
4 30
5 35
```

I would like to keep all the rows that has value - value of the previous row <=5, so I do

```
df['diff'] = df.value.diff()
df = df[df.diff <= 5]
```

Then I will have

```
ID value diff
2 15 5
3 18 3
5 35 5
```

However, I don't want to keep row 3, because row 2 is kept due to row 1, and as row 1 and row 2 become a pair, row 3 should not be paired with row 2 anymore.

How could I do that using pandas? Indeed I can write a for loop but it is not the best idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have the mask that checks if difference to previous row <= 5:

```
>>> d = df.value.diff().le(5)
>>> d
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
```

Rows marked with `True` will be kept, but you don't want to keep a *True* row if the previous row was also *True*.

Then we can shift this mask, negate it and `&` with the original to convert `True`'s that have `True` in previous row into `False`:

```
>>> d & ~d.shift(fill_value=False)
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
```

where `fill_value` is needed otherwise there arises NaN and it "can't bitwise-negate float". Putting `False` there has no effect other than silencing that issue.

Now we can select the rows from the dataframe with this resultant mask:

```
>>> wanted = d & ~d.shift(fill_value=False)
>>> df[wanted]

ID  value
2   15
5   35
```